# Is there an easy way to execute an external java program from within a python script?

Tags: java, python

I have a java program that i run with the following command

```
java -jar <program_name>.jar --<some_parameter> <some_filename>.csv
```

Within my python script I create the <some_filename>.csv. Then, I would like to execute the java program and use the program's stdout output in my python script.

Is there an easy way to do so?

Comment: Take a look at the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `subprocess`:

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.run([COMMAND LIST], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(result.stdout)
```

[COMMAND LIST] is a string list of the words in the command separated by space

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(["java", "-jar <program_name>.jar --<some_parameter> <some_filename>.csv"],shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
if not out:
   print(err.rstrip().decode())
else:
   print(out.rstrip().decode())
```